# How to export a function from a class, so to be able to import it into another class to use

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

To be clear, I am learning TypeScript and React for spfx developments. I have read and taken part in tutorials and other answers on various sources and Stack Overflow and haven't found them enough to help me.

Here is my function in the EvalReqNewForm class (getGrades()):

```
export default class EvalReqNewForm extends React.Component<IEvalReqNewProps, IEvalReqNewState> {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            EvalType: null,
            JobTitReportTo: null,
            JobTitReportToNum: null,
            PropGradeList: [],
            SelectedGrade: undefined,
            CompPos: null,
            ContextNewJobCode: null
        };
        this._onJobTitReportToChange = this._onJobTitReportToChange.bind(this);
        this._onJobTitReportToNumChange = this._onJobTitReportToNumChange.bind(this);
        this._onPropGradeChange = this._onPropGradeChange.bind(this);

    }
```

...

```
public _getGrades() {
        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Grades").items.get().then((items: any[]) =>{
          let returnedGrades:IDropdownOption[]= items.map((item) =>{return {key:item.Title, text:item.Title};});
         this.setState({PropGradeList : returnedGrades});
        });
      }
```

And I want to use the _getGrades() function from the other class to use in a ComponentDidMount() in order to the 'Grades' from the SP list.

Does it involve using props? Or can the function be simply exported and imported into the class where I want to use it?

Please understand I'm learning the basics here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Create a function that only depends on it's parameters and export/import it.

---

> Or can the function be simply exported and imported into the class where I want to use it?

What you can do is create a function that depends only on it's parameters.

So it would be something like

```
export function getGrades(something){
    // do what ever you want with something
    return somethingYouDid
}
```

And then you import it to other files and use it like

```
import { getGrades } from '...'

...

public _getGrades() {
    const results = getGrades(someDataFromSomeWhere)
    this.setState({PropGradeList : results});        
}
```

I also see that you are using promises, so maybe you will need to use `async`/`await` in your case.

## Edit:

As said in the comments

> I can't seem to use export within a class

You should use it out side of the class, you will have to functions.
One out side of the class that have all the logic and other inside that class that only calls the outside function.

```
export function getGrades(something){
    // do what ever you want with something
    return somethingYouDid
}

class ... {

    ...

    public _getGrades() {
        const results = getGrades(someDataFromSomeWhere)
        this.setState({PropGradeList : results});        
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't seem to use export within a class. It says 'export modifier cannot appear on a class element'.

Comment: @Tom please check my edit, you should have a function outside of the class

Comment: I've given it a work-around by using a componentdidmount() in the other class, so I have 2 componentDidMounts in the webpart. Is there any harm in that in the long run?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `I have 2 componentDidMounts in the webpart`, do you mean in the same class? That will give you an error

Comment: Thanks Vencovsky, ignore the componentDidMount() question, sorry. In your example above, should your it say that the outside function should call the inside function and the inside function should have the logic? Or does it matter which way round it goes? Sorry, utter noob here.

Comment: @Tom the function outside of the class should have the logic and the function inside the class should call the function outside of the class. So the function outside should have things like `.map` or async calls and the function inside the class should have things like `this.setState`.

Comment: Thanks that all makes sense. I'm not sure whether you could help me further? Perhaps in chat? I have created what I think should be correct in response to your suggestions but need a little guidance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199521/discussion-between-tom-and-vencovsky).